# sending direct message to a follower using twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter

I want send a direct message to one of my follower of twitter through my android application.

I can get the list of user_ids of all my followers by using twitter4j api through following code .

```
int[] followers=mTwitter.getFollowersList();

for(int i=0;i<followers.length;i++){
Log.e("follower name :",String.valueOf(followers[i]));
}
```

bur i don't know how to send a direct message to a follower .

Is it possible , and how ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#directMessage

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '207015258102038528' as integer
 at twitter4j.internal.util.ParseUtil.getInt(ParseUtil.java:120) exception by using that code .

Comment: looks like it's a bug in twitter4j. You need to be sure that you're using the latest snapshot. you may want to read the details in this discussion: https://groups.google.com/group/twitter4j/browse_thread/thread/43fba799c09b3982

Comment: Thanks for your reply its working good for twitter4j-core-2.1.10.jar .